# Finding variables in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for error checking while searching a list, I ran into an issue with loading an unloading. I am looking for a way to have the script return what variable failed.

```
thisList = ['tacos', 'beer', 'cheese']

try:
    x = thisList.index('beer')
    y = thisList.index('eggs')
except ValueError as e:
    DO AWESOME
```

At this point I would like single out y. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? The error message will include the string that wasn't found (although not the name it was assigned to, as there may be more than one). If you want to know which fails, why put them all in the same `try`?

Comment: You could use two separate `try/except` blocks, or write a helper method, like `find` for strings, that returns `-1` or `None` in case of "not found" and check the result for `x` and `y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible using a single `try/except`.

Instead, you could either use one `try/except` for each of the problematic lines...

```
try:
    x = thisList.index('beer')
except ValueError as e:
    print("x not found")
try:
    y = thisList.index('eggs')
except ValueError as e:
    print("y not found")
```

... or write yourself a helper function, like `find` for strings, that instead of raining an exception returns some special sentinel value that you can check afterwards.

```
def find(l, e):
    try:
        return l.index(e)
    except ValueError:
        return -1

x = find(thisList, 'beer') # x is  1
y = find(thisList, 'eggs') # y is -1
```

Comment: That last piece of code is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks